# How to receive multiuserchat message in smack 4.1.5

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, multiuserchat

Is there any method like ChatManagerListener for receiving the entire multiuser chats ?

I found  muc.addMessageListener and PacketFilter but both are dependent on the group name.

I need to listen group messages based on connection object.

I viewed [How to properly listen for MultiUserChat in Smack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808798/how-to-properly-listen-for-multiuserchat-in-smack)
but not appropriate for the current requirement.

Comment: refer this code : https://github.com/pfleidi/yaxim

Comment: Sorry.many methods are deprecated.